# not able to write for loop in XQuery MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am trying to write a for loop as :

```
for $conditions in $contents
return fn:concat("The value of contents is : ", $conditions)
```

However in place of pages its returning the values inside the `$contents` variable.

I am working on a mapping file in marklogic and trying to get the values of the elements from that mapping file.

```
"contents": {
      "sample": {
        "feature": ".........",
        "contents": "value1",
        "contents": {..................}
```

now I want to loop for the "contents" element from the mapping file but my for loop is returning me the whole "contents" map instead of giving output as : "The value of contents is: value1"
Can anyone help in this regard?

Comment: You need to give some idea of what $books contains. A for clause iterates over a sequence. If $books doesn't contain a sequence this would be the expected behaviour.

Comment: Please provide enough information so the problem can be reproduced: a specimen source document, and a complete query; show the required output and the actual output.

Comment: When you say "the values inside the $books variable" what is likely happening is that you are giving it a $book which may have an XML structure, and when using it in a function such as `fn:contains()` it produces the string value of that book, which would be the concatenation of all of it's `text()` nodes. It's helpful if you provide an example of the $books, what it currently is producing as output, and what you want it to produce.

Comment: It may be that you need to adjust the XPath to select the pages under the `$books`, but unless we can see what `$books` is, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, as mentioned by others as well, but let me hazard a guess. You sometimes want to count items. You can do that with something as simple as `fn:count($books)`.

In other cases you might want to keep track at which item number you are currently. In other programming languages you might write a for-loop which increments a variable with `i = i + 1`. You can't do that in XQuery, since it is a functional language, and those typically do not allow this.

There are ways around in MarkLogic, but there is a simple trick. The FLWOR statement can keep track of the current position for you using the `at` keyword.

You use it like this:

```
for $item at $page in $books
return fn:concat("This is the page number... ", $page)
```

HTH!

Comment: This just gives me the count. I want the value inside the page. not able to get that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the contents of $books? Your question is rather short. Can you edit it, and provide more detail?